# Removing two letters only if they appear at end of a field in QGIS labels

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, labeling, string, replace

I am trying to remove the letters `'a'` and `'o'` only if they appear at the end of the field `'name'` while labeling. For example, I'm working with names like:

> Ontario, Manitoba, Alberta, Quebec, Nova Scotia

Effectively, I am trying to achieve something like:

> Ontari, Manitob, Albert, Quebec, Nova Scoti

But if I were to use the expression
`replace(name, 'a', '')`
then all the 'a's would disappear like:

> Ontrio, Mnitob, Albert, Quebec, Nov Scoti

Any ideas on how I should revise the code? I have already tried incorporating things like `'%a'` and `right(name, 1) = 'a'` to no avail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possible expression would be:

```
CASE WHEN
RIGHT("name", 1) IN('a', 'o') 
THEN substr("name", 0, length("name")-1)
ELSE "name"
END
```

In addition to your `right("name",1)`, `substr()` part works to remove 1 letter from the original length of the "name" field.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could use `regex_replace`

> **function regexp_replace**
>
> Returns a string with the supplied regular expression replaced.
>
> Syntax
> `regexp_replace(input_string,regex,replacement)`
>
> Arguments
>
> **input_string**
> the string to replace matches in
>
> **regex**
> The regular expression to replace. Backslash characters must be double escaped (e.g., "\s" to match a white space character).
>
> **replacement**
> The string that will replace any matching occurrences of the supplied regular expression. Captured groups can be inserted into the replacement string using \1, \2, etc.

So in your case something like:

```
regexp_replace("name",'[ao]$','')
```